# Setting active MapTool to an internal QGIS tool from python

Tags: pyqgis

I'm working on a plugin which could change QGIS active tool for the user.

I can select the canvas and get currently active map tool like this:

```py
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
tool = canvas.mapTool()
# -> <qgis._gui.QgsMapToolIdentify object at 0x1b1e2b310>
```

I know about [`.setMapTool()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/gui/QgsMapCanvas.html#qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas.setMapTool) as a QgsMapCanvas method to set map tool, but I couldn't find the QgsMapTool instances for QGIS default tools that I could pass to this method.

From this point how can I switch to QGIS 'Select features' map tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the native selection tools found in the Selection Toolbar, you can just programmatically trigger their actions. So, in a plugin (where the `iface` object is an instance attribute referenced as `self.iface`) you would just use any of the following lines, depending which selection tool you want to activate:

```py
self.iface.actionSelectRectangle().trigger()
self.iface.actionSelectFreehand().trigger()
self.iface.actionSelectPolygon().trigger()
self.iface.actionSelectRadius().trigger()
```